# .config/gnome-control-center d-w-r-xr-T. meaning

Tags: permissions, gnome, gnome3

```
> cd /home/ron
> du -sh .

  du: cannot read directory ‘./.config/gnome-control-center’: Permission denied

> ls -l

  d-w-r-xr-T. 2 ron users   10 Jul 31  2021 gnome-control-center

> cd ~/.config/gnome-control-center

  -bash: cd: gnome-control-center: Permission denied
```

in RHEL 7.9 x86-64 installed as "Server with GUI", can someone explain the `d-w-r-xr-T` and is that correct and if so why?  And why is this subfolder in my home account not accessible by me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you applied `chmod 1254` permissions to `~/.config/gnome-control-center` but if you didn't maybe the RedHat installation did it. I checked that directory in my `RedHat 9` and I got this perms:

```
drwx------. 3 redhat redhat 25 Apr  6 19:20 gnome-control-center
```

*Maybe old RedHat versions used the permissions you have*

Regarding your permissions: `d-w-r-xr-T ron users` you can notice that your current user `ron` has not exectuion/read permissions. Thus when you try to `cd` you get `Permission denied` (because of the execution permissions are missing). The same applies when you try to **read** the directory because of the **read** permissions are missing:

```
$> ls ./.config/gnome-control-center
ls: cannot open directory './.config/gnome-control-center': Permission denied
```

I think your user `redhat` is in the group `users` and maybe you are wondering why you cannot access to that directory even if the group permissions are `r-x`. That behavior is correct and is related to [path resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html):

> The permission bits of a file consist of three groups of three bits,
> cf. chmod(1) and stat(2). The first group of three is used when the
> effective user ID of the calling process equals the owner ID of the
> file. The second group of three is used when the group ID of the file
> either equals the effective group ID of the calling process ....

About `T` in your perms: `d-w-r-xr-T` that's related to **sticky bit**. The `T` is used when the `others` permissions have not `execution` perms.
So if you want to get `t` you should use:

```bash
chmod o+x gnome-control-center
```

Comment: thanks.  I have 100+ users defined in `/etc/passwd` and only my account and one other has a `.config/gnome-control-center` folder.  And the one other user also has `d-w-r-xr-T` permissions, I'm sure not done by him, so it must be something happening under the hood when messing with gnome desktop display stuff.  And it is an empty folder.

Comment: @ron What happens when you open `gnome-control-center` and make some changes? Are you allowed? (It should not be). I've noticed that the folder is created when you use `gnome-control-center` (the first time) and makes some changes, for example, changing the desktop background

Comment: I can confirm... `rm -r gnome-control-center`; then open `Applications - Settings` and change Background and/or LockScreen and it results in `~/.config/gnome-control-center` folder being created with `d-w-r-xr-T` permissions with ownership as `ron.users`. This is rhel 7.9 at `3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64`

Comment: I suspect after RHEL 7.9 install from dvd it was getting the `redhat.redhat` permissions, that has been corrected in subsequent updates, but maybe a bug that's gone unrecognized for the `chmod` being done resulting in `d-w-r-xr-T` ?

Comment: @ron I'm not sure why you were allowed to make any change since the user has no exection and read permissions for that directory. But maybe `SELinux` allows you to make any change (the dot `.` at the end of the perms: `d-w-r-xr-T.`) means the that file  has SELinux security context

Comment: @ron I do think that the bug can be related to the `gnome-control-software` application. Maybe this ones creates the directory but with wrong permissions. Or maybe its correct that behavior and as I said maybe `SELinux` allows you to make changes (I've never used SELinux so I do not understand how this works)